# Joining three tables with a circular relationship between them in mysql or sqlserver

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

So I've been back and forth between NoSQL databases and relational ones, and I can't solve some problems that are solvable pretty easily in NoSql databases. So here's the issue that I'm struggling with right now:

We have an article table with articles' information in it, and a user will submit an article to the system. Each user can submit many articles but each article is written by only one user, so we have a one-to-many relationship here. Now there should be favorites list for users' favorite articles, meaning that any user can have many articles as his/her favorite ones, and each article can be favorited (if that's a verb) by many users. Hence we have a many-to-many relationship and we create a new table called favorites with `user_id` and `article_id` in it as columns. Here's a summary of my current design of the tables which have a circular relationship currently.

**Users:**

```
id | name
----------
```

**Articles:**

```
id | title | text | user_id |  //here user_id is the writer of the article
-----------------------------
```

**Favorites:**

```
id | user_id | article_id |  //here user_id the id of the user
---------------------------  //who favorited the article that article_id 
                             //that article_id points to
```

So what I want to query now is a result table, that will give me a user's favorite articles' information about the article itself, its writer information AND information of the user to whom this favorite item belong. Something like this:

```
userName | favoriteArticleTitle | favoriteArticleText | favoriteArticleWriter
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Because the user in the first column and the user from the last column come from the same table, I cannot think of a way to join these three tables and get the `user.name` column without causing an ambiguity.

So my question is how can I achieve a result like I want (if it is even possible)?l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply alias the columns in your `SELECT`

```
SELECT [userName] = u.name
     , [favoriteArticleTitle] = a.title
     , [favoriteArticleText] = a.text
     , [favoriteArticleWriter] = au.name
  FROM users u
         INNER JOIN favorites f ON u.id = f.user_id
         INNER JOIN articles a ON f.article_id = a.user_id
         INNER JOIN users au ON a.user_id = au.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a left join the user table twice, one with the favourites and the other with the article table for as follows:

```
SELECT b.name AS userName, c.title AS faverateArticleTitle, c.text AS favoritArticleText, d.name AS favorateArticleWriter
FROM Favorites AS a 
LEFT JOIN users AS b ON (a.user_id = b.id)
LEFT JOIN Articles AS c ON (a.article_id = c.id)
LEFT JOIN users AS d ON (c.user_id = d.id)
```